# Prove an algorithm on the Thue-Morse sequence by induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

For the purposes of this question, I'm subscribing to the following definition of the Thue-Morse sequence:

Let $T_0 = 0$, and $C$ be the bitwise complement function. $T_n = T_{n - 1} + C(T_{n - 1})$.

I'm working on an exercise that proves that when the Lindenmeyer algorithm is applied to a Thue-Morse sequence $T_n$, it produces the next string $T_{n + 1}$ in the Thue-Morse sequence. It is supposed to be done by induction. Below is the actual question and my proof:

**(b)** For every $n$, if $0$ is replaced by $01,$ and $1$ is replaced by $10$ simultaneously everywhere in $T_{n}$, the result is $T_{n+1}$.

**Base Case:** Let $n_{0}=0$. $T_{n_{0}}=T_{0}=0$. If we replace the $0$ with $01,$ we end up with $01,$ which equals $T_{1}$.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that for $n \geq n_{0},$ the proposition holds.

**Induction Step:** Prove that for $n+1$, submitting $T_{n+1}$ to the aforementioned algorithm yields $T_{n+2}$. Let $F$ be the aforementioned algorithm that operates on bitwise strings, and let $C$ be the complement function, that is, bitwise negation. Note that $F(C(0))=$ $C(F(0))=10,$ and $F(C(1))=C(F(1))=01,$ and more generally, $F(C(x))=C(F(x))$ where $x$ is a bitwise string. Therefore we need to prove:

\begin{aligned}
T_{n+2} &=F\left(T_{n+1}\right) \\
T_{n+1}+C\left(T_{n+1}\right) &=F\left(T_{n+1}\right) \\
F\left(T_{n}\right)+C\left(F\left(T_{n}\right)\right) &=F\left(T_{n+1}\right) \\
F\left(T_{n}\right)+F\left(C\left(T_{n}\right)\right) &=F\left(T_{n+1}\right) \\
F\left(T_{n}+C\left(T_{n}\right)\right) &=F\left(T_{n+1}\right) \\
F\left(T_{n}+C\left(T_{n}\right)\right) &=F\left(T_{n}+C\left(T_{n}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}

I think the proof is sound, but I just can't tell if I'm making correct use of my Induction Hypothesis. It seems OK, but something feels a little off, so I'm looking for some constructive criticism on what I've got. Any advice or direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You should state the definition of $T_n$ that you are using.  Some people would define $T_n$ by the Lindenmeyer algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps that make me take a second look to figure out why.

- $F(A+B)=F(A)+F(B)$
- $F(C(x))=C(F(x))$

---

- We have  $F(A+B)=F(A)+F(B)$ where $+$ denots concatenation because $F$ is a bitwise replacement of constant length.
- Similarly, we have $C(A+B)=C(A)+C(B)$.
- For $F(C(x))=C(F(x))$, I use another induction to see it.

Suppose $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ denotes the concatenation of substring from lef to the right.

\begin{align}
F(C(x)) &= F\left( C\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\right) \\
&= F\left( \sum_{i=1}^n C\left(  x_i\right)\right) \\
&=F\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} C\left(  x_i\right) + C(x_n)\right) \\
&=F\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} C\left(  x_i\right)\right) + F(C(x_n)) \\
&=C\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} F\left(  x_i\right)\right) + C(F(x_n)) \\
&= C(F(x))
\end{align}

---

We want to show that $$T_{n+2}=F(T_{n+1})$$

Proof:
\begin{align}
F(T_{n+1}) &= F(T_n + C(T_n)), \text{ by definition} \\
&= F(T_n) + F(C(T_n)) , \text{ since } F(A+B)=F(A)+F(B)\\
&= T_{n+1} + C(F(T_n)), \text{ by induction hypothesis and since } F(C(x))=C(F(x))\\
&= T_{n+1} + C(T_{n+1}), \text{ by induction hypothesis}\\
&= T_{n+2},  \text{by definition}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really good! I see it is similar to my proof, however you kept your $T_{n+2}$ side of the equation the same the entire time, which is more clear. Give that, would you say my proof is correct (but just some parts are unnecessary, or do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: I think there is a lack of clarity though I think you know what you are doing. That is from a line to another line, try to justify them. Also, reasoning for $F(C(x))=C(F(x))$ is too fast for me to absorb.